# pure javascript onclick becomes undefined after assigning functions scope ends

Tags: javascript, html

It's been a while since I wrote Javascript without jQuery, so please bear with me. I'm assuming I'm just doing something silly. I have this function that converts link urls to an internal representation that I use with a router I wrote.

```
Templater.prototype.replace_links = function() {
    this.links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (i = 0; i < this.links.length; i++) {
        if (!(this.links[i].getAttribute("href") === this.VOID && this.links[i].getAttribute(this.HREF))) {
            this.links[i].setAttribute(this.HREF, this.links[i].getAttribute("href"));
            this.links[i].setAttribute("href", this.VOID);
            this.links[i].onClick = function(self, link) {
                return function() { self.router.go(link.getAttribute(self.HREF)); };
            }(this, this.links[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called the first time when Templater is initialized. The first time it works correctly. However, I run it a second time after I append some html into the body of the document. I run it again just in case that appended html has links in it too:

```
<body>
    <!-- arbitrary new html is loaded in here -->
    <a href="login">Login</a> <!-- becomes <a href="javascript:void(0)" lite-href="login">Login</a> correctly -->
    <a href="home">Home</a> <!-- becomes <a href="javascript:void(0)" lite-href="home">Home</a> correctly -->
</body>
```

When I console.log(this.links[0], this.links[0].onClick) after the function has been run but still within a Templater function, I get the correct html and then `undefined` for the onClick event:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" lite-href="discover">Discover</a> undefined
```

When I log the same to values within the replace_links scope, I get what I'm expecting. I.e. the function is shown:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" lite-href="Discover">Discover</a> function () { self.router.go(link.getAttribute(self.HREF)); }
```

I was playing around with it some more and tried this way and got the same kind of thing.

```
Templater.prototype.replace_links = function() {
    this.links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (i = 0; i < this.links.length; i++) {
        if (!(this.links[i].getAttribute("href") === this.VOID && this.links[i].getAttribute(this.HREF))) {
            (function(self, link) {
                link.setAttribute(self.HREF, link.getAttribute("href"));
                link.setAttribute("href", self.VOID);
                link.onClick = function() { self.router.go(link.getAttribute(self.HREF)); };
            })(this, this.links[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I console.log after the replace_link scope ends like before and this time I still get:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" lite-href="discover">Discover</a> undefined
```

I'd really appreciate any help and/or suggestions! Please let me know if I'm missing anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key points here have been treated as minor details.

> I append some html into the body of the document

and

> this.links[i].onClick = function(self, link) {

My point is, if you alter `innerHTML`, which I assume is the way you "append some html into the body of the document," the browser will serialize the DOM objects into HTML, do the string concatenation, and then parse it again. This results in new objects which no longer have the expandos, such as `onClick`. `onClick` is a custom property; you probably meant `onclick` anyway.

However, some of your changes will be serialized and parsed successfully, namely the `setAttribute` operations. Thus, when you run `replace_links` after the HTML appending, the

```
if (!(this.links[i].getAttribute("href") === this.VOID && this.links[i].getAttribute(this.HREF)))
```

check will treat the link as already replaced and not assign the `onClick` again.

Here's a fiddle that shows this in action. http://jsfiddle.net/k9d7b2ds/

Comment: Excellent. That is very helpful and I had no idea. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Made some additional changes. The onclick event's default `this` object is always referencing the window object.  You need to pass over the closure.

Check sample code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/y0443fz6/

```
Templater.prototype.replace_links = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (i = 0; i < this.links.length; i++) {
        if (!(this.links[i].getAttribute("href") === this.VOID && this.links[i].getAttribute(this.HREF))) {
            this.links[i].setAttribute(this.HREF, this.links[i].getAttribute("href"));
            this.links[i].setAttribute("href", this.VOID);
            this.links[i].onclick = function(self, link) {                
                return function() {
                  self.router.go(link.getAttribute(self.HREF)); 
                };
            }(that, this.links[i]);
        }
        console.log(this.links[i], this.links[i].onclick);
    }

}
```

hope that helps.  gl

Comment: Yes I did try both of these as well. This did not make a difference. I'm pretty sure I was consistent with my use of onclick vs onClick throughout the demonstrated code.

Comment: ok, made some changes and added fiddle demo.  the click events and log are working as expected.